# Android-App consume to much energy. Sockets maybe the reason

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, energy

In my app I use a datagramSocket, one serversocket and several sockets. When my app runs on my android-device, the phone get hot on one area and it needs lots of energy.
I think the reason for the problem are my Sockets. But Im not sure which opperation are so energy-consuming:

Does it cost much energy to create new Sockets:

```
Socket so = new Socket();
ss = new ServerSocket( port );
mSocket = new MulticastSocket( port );
```

Is it importand to close the serversocket and other sockets if I don't need it anymore.

Does connecting cost energy?

```
so.connect( new InetSocketAddress(ip, port ), 1000);
```

And after connecting does the connection need much energy?(Is it better to disconnect when i don't send datas for a long time)
Does a high amount of Sockets need much energy?

I also have several threads:

Beside my main-thread and three binderthreads, I have three more:

1st Thread: listen for incoming message on my datagram-socket:

```
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer. length);
mSocket .receive(packet);
```

2nd Thread: listen for incoming messages on several sockets:

```
try {
      if (objectInputStreamList .size() != 0){
            if (counter >= objectInputStreamList .size()){
                 counter = 0;
             }
             ObjectInputStream ois = objectInputStreamList .get(counter);
             Object o = ois.readObject();
             if (o instanceof Message){
                 receive((Message) o);
             System.out .println("Message received in Server");
                 }
             }
     } catch (SocketTimeoutException soTOE){
        counter++;
     }
```

3rd Thread: send Datas via an http-request via internet to a server.

Does one of the threads need much energy?

The app needs also much energy even if wifi is turned off or wifi is turned on but not connected to wlan.
And so there are no connections.

Which of this opperations are energyconsuming? And what can I do to reduce the energy?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: and, are you closing sockets ?

Comment: they running all the time dispite the serversocket. I close it after connection. But the sockets and datagrammSocket run all the time. I need them to get messages. Is this energyconsuming?

Comment: If it is running even after closing connection, then it is really energy consuming.

Comment: No, I mean I close the serversocket after an connection between the sockets of two devices is established. The sockets getting closed after disconnecting.

Comment: Sounds like you have some sort of a while loop that is spinning very tightly, thus consuming alot of CPU (which in turn uses alot of energy/battery). Its not immediately obvious from the code you posted, but it looks like it could be the 2nd thread. Is the code you posted for the 2nd thread inside of a while loop? Seems like it should be. Im not familiar with all of those objects/method calls in the 2nd thread, but it doesnt seem like any are blocking, waiting for input. You should be calling a blocking method which will make the while loop not spin so tightly/frequently.

Comment: Yes it is inside a whileloop. But I use readObject() isn't it a blocking method. Every 300ms there is a timeout that it got listen on the next socket for 300ms. So the loop get called 3 times a second, i think. Is this too much?

Answer (score 0):

Given that it runs hot even when it's not supposed to do anything, I suspect one of your threads are running freely instead of properly blocking. Can't tell you more without the complete source code, but some good old printf debugging might come in handy. Simply put different logging statements in each of your while loops and run the program. If a statement fills your log at an alarming rate, then there you have it.

Yes you should always close a socket that you no longer need. For example, if you don't close your server sockets then their ports will remain occupied. Eventually the system will run out of ports. (I could come up with many other reasons, including resource usage and elegance. Tidying things up might even make the problem obvious.)

FYI having many sockets open does not cost energy in and of itself. Network activity costs a little energy (pay attention to [idle timers](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html)!), but it shouldn't make one part of your device really hot.